# Groovy - Reading files from tomcat server

Tags: groovy, soapui, file-read

I'm not able to retrieve file contents using Groovy.

Below is the code, error in Soapui

```
portnumber = ":8080"
extractedValues = new File("//hostname"+"${portnumber}"+"/share/test/working/test.csv").getText('UTF-8')
log.info(extractedValues)
```

Error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\hostname:8080\share\test\working\test.csv (The network path was not found) error at line: 54

I feel like the issue is with the port number, thus why I'm passing it in a variable.

The link itself works when logged on the server and trying it from file explorer.

Comment: What you trying to do? is the file on shared machine or from a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are reading a file hosted in a tomcat i.e., an URL.

Here is how you would get the contents of it:

```
def host = 'localhost'
def port = '8080'
def extractedValues = new URL("http://${host}:${port}/share/test/working/test.csv").getText('UTF-8')
log.info extractedValues
```

Comment: great thanks rao, that works.. next phase would be to search for a file in that directory.. any ideas ? i tried list(),listFiles(), contains, no luck.

Comment: May be you want to create a separate question.