# Groovy - find csv file on tomcat server and retrieve content

Tags: groovy, soapui

i need to find a way using groovy to find a file on a tomcat server.
the file contains a unique transaction id generated. example of file below
date_time_transactionID_numbers.csv

so from the above i know the transactionID, however, the directory will contains a over 100 csv files. how do i find the actual file ?

```
def host = 'localhost'
def port = '8080'
def extractedValues = new      URL("http://${host}:${port}/share/test/working/test.csv").getText('UTF-8')
log.info extractedValues
```

Comment: If you want all the files in url (remove the file name in the url). Please see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516080/groovy-file-handling-from-http-url

Comment: why are you using URL as you read it from local machine you directly give path of that tomcat folder.

Comment: you want read the file local tomcat folder right?

Comment: String fileContents = new File('/share/test/working/test.csv').getText('UTF-8') use like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy - Reading files from tomcat server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296419/groovy-reading-files-from-tomcat-server)

Comment: tomcat server is not local. its another server which prints out files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your transaction id number you can pass Like this:

```
def host = 'localhost'
        def port = '8080'
        def transactionID_numbers = 100 //suppose you consider
        def date_time = "20_10_2016"    // suppose if your datetime variable like this
        def pathOfCsv = "${date_time}"+ "_" + "${transactionID_numbers}" + "." +"csv"


def extractedValues = new URL("http://${host}:${port}/share/test/working/${pathOfCsv}").getText('UTF-8')
log.info extractedValues
println "The file content is " + extractedValues
```

Thanks

Comment: this works if the date_time stamp is the same as the tomcat server which. howver, the tomcat server runs on a different timezone. thus, not able to define the date time stamp from our end. so what i need is a way to be able to find the file in the directory based on the transaction id. *****_tranid_***.csv